# Login to external site for Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, authentication, elementor

I am updating a Wordpress website to use Elementor.  The website information is managed by Wordpress whereas the website account and details is managed by a 3rd party.  (Think banking where offers and information are described on the website, but the actual finances are managed by a separate entity.)

I am trying to create a login which will take the credentials and automatically submit and log into the managing site's dashboard.

The original Wordpress site uses a widget where I only need to have the html information for the login laid out.  But I am having trouble reproducing the same effect in Elementor.

I have tried setting up an Elementor login widget using their login creation but it does not allow me to specify an external site to submit the username and password.  It seems to only correspond directly to the current Wordpress site and does not allow me to do an external login.

How can I create a login to 3rd party website using elementor?